# Why this code is giving unexpected output?

Tags: python

Hi I have just started to learn Python programming.
I wrote this code:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
b = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
c = []
d = []

for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[0])):
        d.append(a[i][j]+b[i][j])
    c.append(d)

print(c)
```

I got this output:

```
[[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]]
```

But to my understanding the output should be:

```
[[2, 4, 6], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]]
```

So please someone explain me the output.
Thank you.

Comment: You're not making a copy of `d` when you do `c.append(d)`. So when you append to `d` on the next iteration, it modifies both elements of `c`.

Comment: By far, the best way to understand this code is to step through it in a debugger and watch what the values being processed are.

Comment: There is only one `d` list and it is added to `c` twice, so obviously `c` will have twice the same list.

Comment: Use `c.append(d.copy())` and you'll get your expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the copy statement for your desired output.

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
b = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
c = []
d = []
d1=[]

for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[0])):
        d.append(a[i][j]+b[i][j])
        d1=d.copy() # This will copy the d list to d1 and the append d1 to c by this way d1 will not get appended with the values after[2,4,6]  
    c.append(d1)

print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to debug and got the same answer

```
| i = | j = | d =           |
| --- | --- | ------------- |
|  0  |  0  | [ 2 ]         |
|  0  |  1  | [ 2, 4 ]      |
|  0  |  2  | [ 2, 4, 6 ]   |
end of i = 0 iteration, so d = [ 2, 4, 6 ]
end of i = 0 iteration, so c = [ 2, 4, 6 ]
| i = | j = | d =                    |
| --- | --- | ---------------------- |
|  1  |  0  | [ 2, 4, 6, 8 ]         | 
|  1  |  1  | [ 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 ]     | 
|  1  |  2  | [ 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12 ] | 
end of i = 1 iteration, so d = [ 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12 ]
end of i = 1 iteration, so c = [ [ 2, 4, 6 ], [ 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12 ] ]
```